# Timing and integration with TikZ PGFlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How do I set intervals or integration with TikZ PGFlots?
Something similar to the figure below, but I want to define the function, the intervals of integration and the partitions.
[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,tkz-fct}
\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}   

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=6,ymin=-2,ymax=14,ystep=2]
\tkzDrawX \tkzDrawY
\tkzFct[line width=2pt,color = red, domain =-3:6]{(-\x-2)*(\x-5)}
\tkzDrawRiemannSumSup[fill=blue!40,opacity=.5,interval=-1:5,number=10] 
\tkzDrawRiemannSumInf[fill=green!40,opacity=.5,interval=-1:5,number=10] 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Basically show us what you have tried...

Comment: I've written a simple package, that works solely by including the `pgfplots` package, that draws a variety of types of Riemann sums of either fixed width rectangles of any number or of any number of varying width rectangles in conjunction with a defined function. It also has routines for combining them on one graph with appropriate order of overlap. See my answer to [Placing Coloured Rectangles on a Plot Using Points From the Plot Riemann Sums](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140207/placing-coloured-rectangles-on-a-plot-using-points-from-the-plot-riemann-sums)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're happy with using the midpoint of the partitions for the approximation (instead of the maximum or minimum), you can relatively easily do this in PGFplots.

I've defined a new style `integral=<lower>:<upper>` that draws the rectangles of the approximate integral. You can set the number of partitions by setting `integral segments=<number>` (default is 3).

The style could easily be adjusted to use the left or right point of the partition for the approximation.

For example

```
\pgfset{declare function={f=-15*(x-5)+(x-5)^3+50;}}
\addplot [thick] {f};
\addplot [
    red,
    integral=2:6
] {f}
```

would yield

[image]

Setting the number of partitions:

```
\addplot [
    fill=yellow,
    integral segments=10,
    integral=2:8
] {f};
\addplot [thick] {f};
```

[image]

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    integral segments/.code={\pgfmathsetmacro\integralsegments{#1}},
    integral segments=3,
    integral/.style args={#1:#2}{
        ybar interval,
        domain=#1+((#2-#1)/\integralsegments)/2:#2+((#2-#1)/\integralsegments)/2,
        samples=\integralsegments+1,
        x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-((#2-#1)/\integralsegments)/2}
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgf/declare function={f=-15*(x-5)+(x-5)^3+50;}]
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:10,
    samples=100,
    axis lines=middle
]
\addplot [thick] {f};
\addplot [
    red,
    integral=2:6
] {f};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you take a look at the [tkz-fct](http://www.altermundus.fr/pages/fct.html) package?  It does whole bunch of stuff, including Riemann sums.

Comment: Error message: "Plot data file 'riemann.tkzfct.table' not found". But i use TexLive 2011 and this is complete.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva Could you edit your original post, and add an example showing what you did?

Comment: Do you have gnuplot installed?  The beginning of the manual (http://www.altermundus.fr/downloads/packages/tkz-fct-screen.pdf) explains how the package uses gnuplot, and how to install it.

Comment: The gnuplot is installed but I know that I am not using. Take a simple example and please tell me the steps (commands necessary) to generate the chart. I am using pdflatex.

Comment: Apparently in texlive 2011, gnuplot is not on the list of programs allowed to use write18.  You can run pdflatex with the `--shell-escape` option, it will override the restrictions and execute gnuplot for you.  Or you can execute gnuplot manually between runs of pdflatex.  In this case, you want to run `gnuplot riemann.tkzfct.gnuplot`.  That should create the `.table` file.