# How to use sin function in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

How to use sin function in pgfplots?
In this post [Timing and integration with TikZ PGFlots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30763/timing-and-integration-with-tikz-pgflots/30782#30782) i need
`[/pgf/declare function={f=sin(x);}]` but generate a line, and `[/pgf/declare function={f=sin(x r);}]` not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    integral segments/.code={\pgfmathsetmacro\integralsegments{#1}},
    integral segments=3,
    integral/.style args={#1:#2}{
        ybar interval,
        domain=#1+((#2-#1)/\integralsegments)/2:#2+((#2-#1)/\integralsegments)/2,
        samples=\integralsegments+1,
        x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-((#2-#1)/\integralsegments)/2}
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgf/declare function={f=sin(x);}]
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:10,
    samples=100,
    axis lines=middle
]
\addplot [
    fill=yellow,
    integral segments=20,
    integral=-6:6
] {f};
\addplot [thick] {f};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate and let us know what you mean by "not work".  Ideally you should compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. And details exactly what you have a problem with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you replace `/pgf/declare function={f=sin(x);}` with `/pgf/declare function={f=sin((x)r);}`, the function plots as expected, with the `x` values behaving like radians. If you also change the `integral` domain to `0:2*pi`, you get the following output:

[image]

Comment: I use ``[/pgf/declare function={f=sin(deg(x));}]``. Thanks.

Comment: Jake: The MWE does not suggest this output you have. What else did you change around to restrict the filling to the first two regions?