# Definite Integral Animation Examples

Tags: beamer, animations

Does anyone know where I can find a template that will show Riemann sums converging to the definite integral, dynamically for a [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/) presentation?

Answer (score 19):

With PSTricks.

### *GIF version:*

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\f(#1){(#1+1)*(#1-1)*(#1-3.5)}

\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=100}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{20}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-5.5)(4.5,4.5)
    \psStep[linewidth=0.4pt,linecolor=gray,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange](-0.5,3.0){\i}{\f(x)}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-1.0}{3.5}{\f(x)}
    \psaxes[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-1.5,-5.5)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

### *Beamer version:*

[image]

Read the given comments at the top!

```
% please compile it with pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex
% Filename for this code is main.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{integral.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\f(#1){(#1+1)*(#1-1)*(#1-3.5)}

\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=100}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{20}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-5.5)(4.5,4.5)
    \psStep[linewidth=0.4pt,linecolor=gray,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange](-0.5,3.0){\i}{\f(x)}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-1.0}{3.5}{\f(x)}
    \psaxes[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-1.5,-5.5)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{latex integral}
\immediate\write18{dvips integral}
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf integral.ps}
% do cleaning here if necessary!

\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Definite Integral}
\begin{center}
    \animategraphics[controls,loop,autoplay,scale=0.5]{5}{integral}{}{}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are using Windows operating system and you want to clean the  auxiliary files generated for `integral.pdf`, you can add `\makeatletter\@for\x:={tex,dvi,ps,log,aux}\do{\immediate\write18{cmd /c del integral.\x}}\makeatother` below the comment `% do cleaning here if necessary!`.

Answer (score 18):

Let me borrow Karl's Students's idea.

Here is a `tkz-fct` demonstration. I borrowed the integration from Alain Matthes' answer in [Tikz-PGF: Draw integral test plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40780/tikz-pgf-draw-integral-test-plot). For this to work, you should have [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) installed and compile with `pdflatex` with `-shell-escape` enabled.

### The `.gif` version

[image]

To create the `.gif`, you should install [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) first. After compiling

```
pdflatex -shell-escape tikzintegral
```

run

```
convert -delay 1 -loop 0 tikzintegral.pdf tikzintegral.gif
```

`tikzintegral.tex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}   
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=2+1}{20}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\tkzInit[xmax=8,ymax=4]
\tkzAxeXY[ticks=false]
\tkzGrid   
\tkzFct[color = red, domain =0.125:8]{4./x}
\tkzDrawRiemannSumInf[fill=green!60,
                     opacity=.2,
                     color=green,
                     line width=1pt,
                     interval=1:8,
                     number=\i]
 %\foreach \x/\t in {1.5/$a_1$,2.5/$a_2$,3.5/$a_3$,7.5/$a_7$}
 %\node[green!50!black] at (\x,{4/(\x+1)-0.25}){\t};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

### For the `beamer` presentation

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{tikzintegral.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}   
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=2+1}{20}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\tkzInit[xmax=8,ymax=4]
\tkzAxeXY[ticks=false]
\tkzGrid   
\tkzFct[color = red, domain =0.125:8]{4./x}
\tkzDrawRiemannSumInf[fill=green!60,
                     opacity=.2,
                     color=green,
                     line width=1pt,
                     interval=1:8,
                     number=\i]
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex --shell-escape tikzintegral}

\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Riemann Sum}
    \begin{center}
  \animategraphics[controls,loop,autoplay,scale=0.5]{5}{tikzintegral}{}{}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note here that since you have compiled `tikzintegral.tex` earlier, if you are saving these codes in the same directory, you can just write:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Riemann Sum}
    \begin{center}
        \animategraphics[controls,loop,autoplay,scale=0.5]{5}{tikzintegral}{}{}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is how the first page will look like.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't it make sense to use `figure` in a `frame`?

Comment: @Karl'sstudents I am used to putting `\caption` every time. `:)`

Comment: Oh my ghost. I meant that floating does not make sense in a frame. Try adding `\lipsum[1-20]` before the `figure` and adding `[allowframebreaks]` to the `frame`; you will see that floating is not useful.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes. You are right. I learned something new today, thanks to you.

Comment: One more: You don't need `-shell-escape` in `\immediate\write18{pdflatex -shell-escape tikzintegral}` because there is no external application invocation in `tikzintegral.tex`. :-)

Comment: One more: "Starred" version of `filecontents` environment that you placed above `\documentclass` is useless because it is the same as the unstarred one. As a result, it will not override the existing `tikzintegral.tex` if you make changes in the body of `filecontents*`. If you want the changes to override the existing file, then you have to move the starred `filecontents` environment to the preamble and you have to load `filecontents` package explicitly.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents Wow. Thanks. I learned a lot from you today.

Comment: You can save one byte more by removing one `-` (either the first or the second one) of `--` in `--shell-escape`. :-)