# Weird graph behavior of \tkzDrawRiemannSumInf of the tkz-fct package

Tags: tkz-fct

*I have already emailed the author Alain Matthes regarding this question. But for the benefit of those who might be interested, and since Alain is also a very active member in this site, I am also posting the question here.*

In my attempt to answer the question [Definite Integral Animation Examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106140/definite-integral-animation-examples/106150?noredirect=1#comment231146_106150), I borrowed Alain's code in his answer in [Tikz-PGF: Draw integral test plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40780/tikz-pgf-draw-integral-test-plot). The code works fine but shows an unexpected behavior when passing the value `1` to the `number` option as can be seen in the figure.

[image]

Here, there should be no rectangle after `x=8`. However, the code works fine when `number` is set greater than 1.

Here is the complete code for the figure.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}   

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\tkzInit[xmax=8,ymax=4]
\tkzAxeXY[ticks=false]
\tkzGrid   
\tkzFct[color = red, domain =0.125:8]{4./x}
\tkzDrawRiemannSumInf[fill=green!60,
                     opacity=.2,
                     color=green,
                     line width=1pt,
                     interval=1:8,
                     number=1]
 %\foreach \x/\t in {1.5/$a_1$,2.5/$a_2$,3.5/$a_3$,7.5/$a_7$}
 %\node[green!50!black] at (\x,{4/(\x+1)-0.25}){\t};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can somebody verify this and give a workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it's due to the `\foreach` list having `{0,1,...,x}` and hence forcing `1` to be processed even if x is zero, instead of having `{0,...,x}` hence spining only once. And I guess there is a small typo with `\i` where it is `i` in the code. I'm not sure about the second point.

---

EDIT: Indeed it's not a typo but a rather peculiar syntax. From `fp` readme file.

> ATTENTION: Do not use macro names with `\` for its own.
>   Use only the name or the macro surrounded by `(`, and `)` instead,
>   i.e. do not write `\value{}` but `value` or `(\value)`.
>   This is needed to avoid problems with a prefix "-" of numbers.

---

Here is the fixed version.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}   
\makeatletter
\def\tkz@DrawRiemannSumInf[#1]{%
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{%
/tkzriemann/.cd,
interval        = 1:2,
number          = 10,
opacity         = 0.5,
line width      = 1pt}
\pgfqkeys{/tkzriemann}{#1}  
  \iftkz@init@NO%
     \FPdiv{\tkz@x@delta}{\tkz@init@xorigine}{\tkz@init@xstep}%
     \FPdiv{\tkz@y@delta}{\tkz@init@yorigine}{\tkz@init@ystep}%
  \else
     \FPset{\tkz@x@delta}{0}
     \FPset{\tkz@y@delta}{0}%
  \fi%
\FPadd\tkz@intwd{\tkz@max}{-\tkz@min}
\FPdiv\tkz@delta{\tkz@intwd}{\tkz@fct@nb}
\FPadd\tkz@fct@nb{\tkz@fct@nb}{-1}   

\begin{scope}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\tkz@fct@nb}{%
  \FPeval\x{(\tkz@min+\i*\tkz@delta)}
  \FPeval\tkz@fx{\tkzFcta}
   \let\tkz@firstimg\tkz@fx
    \let\tkz@firstx\x 
  \FPadd\tkz@next{\x}{\tkz@delta}
  \let\tkzFctTmp\tkzFcta
  \FPset\x{\tkz@next}
  \FPeval\tkz@fxnext{\tkzFcta}
\ifdim \tkz@fx pt < \tkz@fxnext pt\relax
 \draw[opacity=\tkz@fct@opacity,/tkzriemann/.cd,#1] (\tkz@firstx ,0 ) rectangle (\tkz@next , \tkz@firstimg/\tkz@init@ystep );
\else 
\draw[opacity=\tkz@fct@opacity,/tkzriemann/.cd,#1] (\tkz@firstx ,0 ) rectangle (\tkz@next , \tkz@fxnext/\tkz@init@ystep );
 \fi  
   }    
   \end{scope}  
\endgroup
} 

\makeatother



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\tkzInit[xmax=8,ymax=4]
\tkzAxeXY[ticks=false]
\tkzGrid   
\tkzFct[color = red, domain =0.125:8]{4./x}
\tkzDrawRiemannSumInf[fill=green!60,
                     opacity=.2,
                     color=green,
                     number=1,
                     line width=1pt,
                     interval=1:8,
                    ]
 %\foreach \x/\t in {1.5/$a_1$,2.5/$a_2$,3.5/$a_3$,7.5/$a_7$}
 %\node[green!50!black] at (\x,{4/(\x+1)-0.25}){\t};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, percusse. About the `\i`, I am not so sure, too. Even in the definitions of `tkzDrawRiemannSum` and `tkzDrawRiemannSumSup` there is only `i` instead of `\i`. But even if `i` is not replaced with `\i`, it works fine with this example.

Comment: @hpesoj626 It seems that it's not a typo

Comment: Yes fine correction I need to modify several macro with the same problem

Comment: It's a bug. I forgot the case with only one rectangle

Comment: @AlainMatthes But still a great family of packages.