# Vertically aligning images in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, vertical-alignment

I have a sequence of images I would like to animate in `beamer`. In each frame, I would like to have two images, say A and B, aligned vertically and centred on the page. All images are the same size.

I tried aligning the images using `\vspace{}`, but then the vertical spaces accumulate and the images slide down as I transition through them.

How should I align the images in each frame?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{
    \begin{figure}[t!]
    \includegraphics<1>[scale=.5]{fig/imageA1} \vspace{.1in}        
    \includegraphics<1>[scale=.5]{fig/imageB1}

    \includegraphics<2>[scale=.5]{fig/imageA2} \vspace{.1in}        
    \includegraphics<2>[scale=.5]{fig/imageB2} 

    \includegraphics<3>[scale=.5]{fig/imageA3} \vspace{.1in}        
    \includegraphics<3>[scale=.5]{fig/imageB3}

    \includegraphics<4>[scale=.5]{fig/imageA4} \vspace{.1in}        
    \includegraphics<4>[scale=.5]{fig/imageB4} 

      \end{figure} 
    }   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try to add a blank line between two images and insert the vertical space there?

Comment: No need to use `[t!]` since `beamer` disables the floating mechanism.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That's good to know, I didn't realize that.

Comment: @Sigur see my response to Kevin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using floating environments (such as  `figure` or `table`) in a frame does not work in the way it should. To accomplish your objective, turn on `allowpagebreak` and `T`. Adjust the graphics with `height` option. See the code below for the remaining.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\frame[allowpagebreak,T]
{%
        \only<1>
        {%
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr0.5\textheight-0.5in]{example-image-a}

            \vfill
            \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr0.5\textheight-0.5in]{example-image-a}
        }%

        \only<2>
        {%
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr0.5\textheight-0.5in]{example-image-b}

            \vfill
            \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr0.5\textheight-0.5in]{example-image-b}
        }%

        \only<3>
        {%
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr0.5\textheight-0.5in]{example-image-c}

            \vfill
            \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr0.5\textheight-0.5in]{example-image-c}
        }%

        \only<4>
        {%
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr0.5\textheight-0.5in]{example-image}

            \vfill
            \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr0.5\textheight-0.5in]{example-image}
        }%
}
\end{document}
```

For creating GIF animation see [my other answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73547/19356).

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it works. How did you generate the gif, by the way?

Comment: @abayesed: If it works the way you want, why don't you accept it with a green check mark below the downward arrow? I will show you how to generate GIF soon.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize you were supposed to do that. This is my first post on TeX.sx.

Comment: Why do you say using figure doesn't work?  It It won't produce a floating object (since beamer disables them), but it gives the possibility of using \caption.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: See [my comment several days ago](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106140/definite-integral-animation-examples/106150#comment231134_106150).

Comment: @Karl'sstudents yes, as I said, beamer disables floating, but that doesn't mean that using figure doesn't work. It works (without flotation) for captioninig tables or figures with the standard \caption command. (Not that I'm a fan of captioning things in a presentation but I know people who does it and even people who requires it).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: OK. I have to say the floating in a frame does not work in the way it should instead.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `\vspace`, you can use `\\` to force a line break.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{
    \begin{figure}[t!]
    \includegraphics<1>[scale=.5]{img} \\
    \includegraphics<1>[scale=.5]{img}

    \includegraphics<2>[scale=.5]{img} \\
    \includegraphics<2>[scale=.5]{img} 

    \includegraphics<3>[scale=.5]{img} \\
    \includegraphics<3>[scale=.5]{img}

    \includegraphics<4>[scale=.5]{img} \\
    \includegraphics<4>[scale=.5]{img} 

      \end{figure} 
    }   
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried forcing a line break this way, but I get an error when I compile saying "There's no line here to end".

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one line break in total instead of one for every image pair, your problem should disappear. The point is that your `\vspace{.1in}` commanded is not masked by the `<1>`,`<2>`,`<3>`, or `<4>`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{
  \begin{figure}[t!]
    \includegraphics<1>[scale=.5]{fig/imageA1}
    \includegraphics<2>[scale=.5]{fig/imageA2}
    \includegraphics<3>[scale=.5]{fig/imageA3}
    \includegraphics<4>[scale=.5]{fig/imageA4}
    \vspace{.1in}        
    \includegraphics<1>[scale=.5]{fig/imageB1}
    \includegraphics<2>[scale=.5]{fig/imageB2}
    \includegraphics<3>[scale=.5]{fig/imageB3}
    \includegraphics<4>[scale=.5]{fig/imageB4}
  \end{figure} 
}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `figure` does not make sense in beamer.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents why is that?

Comment: @abayesed: Because floating in a frame does not work.