# Integral test plot labels not centered

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In the code here:[Tikz-PGF: Draw integral test plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40780/tikz-pgf-draw-integral-test-plot/40786#40786), they have their a sub n's centered in their rectangles. I have taken their code and edited it a bit, but my a_n's are not centered anymore. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgf/declare function={f=1/x;}]
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm, height = 6cm}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,xmax=9,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    domain=0:10,
    samples=100,
    axis lines=center,
    grid=major,
    no marks,
]
\addplot [
    black!50,
    fill=blackwhite,
    right segments=8,
    right=1:9,
] {f};
\addplot [thick, bluedark] {f};
\end{axis}
\foreach \x/\t in {1.5/$a_1$,2.5/$a_2$,3.5/$a_3$,7.5/$a_7$}
\node[black] at (\x,{4/(\x+1)-0.25}){\t}; 
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{center}
```

Comment: Can you make a complete example? `right segments` is not a standard key, and you have several custom colours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinate system inside an `axis` is different from the general coordinate system of the `tikzpicture`, so you need to place your nodes *inside* the `axis`.

That said, there are two caveats:

- Because of how the `axis` is parsed, you can't use a `\foreach` loop quite like normal. Read section 8.1 *Utility commands* in the `pgfplots` manual. In the code below there are two different options.
- Unless you have `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` (or a higher version), coordinates are still not in axis units, unless you use `(axis cs:x,y)` instead of `(x,y)`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% right hand sums
\pgfplotsset{
    right segments/.code={\pgfmathsetmacro\rightsegments{#1}},
    right segments=3,
    right/.style args={#1:#2}{
        ybar interval,
        domain=#1+((#2-#1)/\rightsegments):#2+((#2-#1)/\rightsegments),
        samples=\rightsegments+1,
        x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-((#2-#1)/\rightsegments)}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={f(\x)=1/(\x);} % <-- modified
]
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=9,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    domain=0:10,
    samples=100,
    axis lines=center,
    grid=major,
    no marks,
    width=12cm,
    height = 6cm
]
\addplot [
    black!50,
    fill=black!40!white,
    right segments=8,
    right=1:9,
] {f(x)}; % <-- modified

\addplot [thick, blue!80!black] {f(x)}; % <-- modified

% option 1
%\foreach \x/\t in {1.5/$a_1$,2.5/$a_2$,3.5/$a_3$,7.5/$a_7$}
%  {
%  \edef\temp{\noexpand\node[black] at (axis cs:\x,{f(\x+0.5)/2}) {\t};}
%  \temp
%}

% option 2
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,3,4,8}{%
   \node at (axis cs:#1+0.5,{f(#1+1)/2}) {$a_{#1}$};
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{center}
\end{document}
```