# Trapezium rule for integration using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have problem to draw graphic with LaTeX (especially `TikZ`)?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: For more detail my question in my post (with title : How todraw graphic in LaTeX ?) at  wordpress http://h1rwant0.wordpress.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=68&action=edit&message=6&postpost=v2

Comment: @doncheery, i don't know how make it ? Again, i don't konw how make to draw graphic curve with Tikz? I'm really really new user in LaTeX ...

Comment: have you seen [How to plot integral as summation, as pictured?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75834) and [Tikz-PGF: Draw integral test plot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40780)

Comment: Assuming you are new user to LaTeX and TikZ Please have a look at [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/15717) and [Materials for learning TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15779/15717) to start going

Comment: Sort of related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47532/lower-and-upper-riemann-sums

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could also use [PGFPlots](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) for plotting your function and the integral. The trapeziums can be generated by plotting the function twice with a low sampling frequency: Once using the `ycomb` style for the vertical lines, and once using the default `sharp plot` for the connecting lines.

If you need to do this for several plot, you can define some styles to make it easier to keep everything consistent. That way, you can get the following image

[image]

using the following code:

```
\begin{axis}[
    integral axis,
    ymin=0,
    xmin=0.75, xmax=11.25,
    domain=1.5:10.5,
    xtick={2,...,10},
    xticklabels={$a=x_0$, $x_1$,,,$x_{j-1}$,$x_j$,,$x_{n-1}$,$b=x_n$},
]
% The function
\addplot [very thick, cyan!75!blue] {f} node [anchor=south] {$y=f(x)$};

% The filled area under the approximate integral
\addplot [integral fill=cyan!15] {f} \closedcycle;

% The approximate integral
\addplot [integral line=black] {f};

% The vertical lines between the segments
\addplot [integral, ycomb] {f};

% The highlighted segment
\addplot [integral fill=cyan!35, domain=6:7, samples=2] {f} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
```

---

Here's the complete document with all the styles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots} %http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, set layers=standard}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    integral axis/.style={
        axis lines=middle,
        enlarge y limits=upper,
        axis equal image, width=12cm,
        xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
        ytick=\empty,
        xticklabel style={font=\small, text height=1.5ex, anchor=north},
        samples=100
    },
    integral/.style={
            domain=2:10,
            samples=9
    },
    integral fill/.style={
            integral,
            draw=none, fill=#1,
            on layer=axis background
        },
        integral fill/.default=cyan!10,
        integral line/.style={
            integral,
            very thick,
            draw=#1
        },
        integral line/.default=black
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % The function that is used for all the plots
    declare function={f=x/5-cos(deg(x*1.85))/2+2;}
]
\begin{axis}[
    integral axis,
    ymin=0,
    xmin=0.75, xmax=11.25,
    domain=1.5:10.5,
    xtick={2,...,10},
    xticklabels={$a=x_0$, $x_1$,,,$x_{j-1}$,$x_j$,,$x_{n-1}$,$b=x_n$},
]
% The function
\addplot [very thick, cyan!75!blue] {f} node [anchor=south] {$y=f(x)$};

% The filled area under the approximate integral
\addplot [integral fill=cyan!15] {f} \closedcycle;

% The approximate integral
\addplot [integral line=black] {f};

% The vertical lines between the segments
\addplot [integral, ycomb] {f};

% The highlighted segment
\addplot [integral fill=cyan!35, domain=6:7, samples=2] {f} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

In case you're not using the newest version of PGFPlots (1.8), the `set layers` and `on axis` keys will not be defined. In that case, you can remove those keys and rearrange the `\addplot` command to make sure everything's drawn in the right order:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots} %http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    integral axis/.style={
        axis lines=middle,
        enlarge y limits=upper,
        axis equal image, width=12cm,
        xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
        ytick=\empty,
        xticklabel style={font=\small, text height=1.5ex, anchor=north},
        samples=100
    },
    integral/.style={
            domain=2:10,
            samples=9
    },
    integral fill/.style={
            integral,
            draw=none, fill=#1,
            %on layer=axis background
        },
        integral fill/.default=cyan!10,
        integral line/.style={
            integral,
            very thick,
            draw=#1
        },
        integral line/.default=black
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % The function that is used for all the plots
    declare function={f=x/5-cos(deg(x*1.85))/2+2;}
]
\begin{axis}[
    integral axis,
    ymin=0,
    xmin=0.75, xmax=11.25,
    domain=1.5:10.5,
    xtick={2,...,10},
    xticklabels={$a=x_0$, $x_1$,,,$x_{j-1}$,$x_j$,,$x_{n-1}$,$b=x_n$},
    axis on top
]
% The filled area under the approximate integral
\addplot [integral fill=cyan!15] {f} \closedcycle;

% The highlighted segment
\addplot [integral fill=cyan!35, domain=6:7, samples=2] {f} \closedcycle;

% The function
\addplot [very thick, cyan!75!blue] {f} node [anchor=south] {$y=f(x)$};

% The approximate integral
\addplot [integral line=black] {f};

% The vertical lines between the segments
\addplot [integral, ycomb] {f};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @HirWanto: Pleasure! Please don't forget to upvote all answers you find helpful (by clicking the upward pointing triangle next to the answers), and to come back and accept the one you end up using (by clicking the tick mark next to the answer).

Comment: Hello , 2Jake ,  i tried your command and I can show   trapezium  rule for integration in my  pdf reader,

Comment: Hello , @Jake ,  i tried your command and I can show   trapezium  rule for integration in my  pdf reader,
but I  have problem also with your   command is **\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, set layers=standard}** .On My opinion,  
I try to remove your command : \pgfplotsset{compat=newest, set layers=standard}, 
and the result is I can show  in My PDF Reader…. How is your opinion ?

Comment: @HirWanto: You're probably not using the newest version (1.8) of PGFPlots (the `set layers` key was only introduced recently). I've added an example that should work correctly with older versions of PGFPlots.

Comment: What is PGFplots ... ?? Where i can get the newest version pgf plots

Comment: @HirWanto: PGFPlots is a package that builds on top of the TikZ package. It allows you to create plots of data and functions. It's used in my answer. It is loaded using the command `\usepackage{pgfplots}`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8487/discussion-between-hir-wanto-and-jake)

Comment: @Jake i added the ctan pgfplots links to help newcomers. Hope its ok :).

Answer (score 12):

Here's one possibility; some coordinates are placed first; then we fill the path with the zigzag lines; then, using the coordinates and the `to[out=<angle>,in=<angle>]` syntax, the curve is built; next, vertical lines are added, and finally the axes and some labels are placed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (p1) at (0.7,3);
\coordinate (p2) at (1,3.3);
\coordinate (p3) at (2,2.5);
\coordinate (p4) at (3,2.5);
\coordinate (p5) at (4,3.5);
\coordinate (p6) at (5,4.1);
\coordinate (p7) at (6,3.4);
\coordinate (p8) at (7,4.1);
\coordinate (p9) at (8,4.6);
\coordinate (p10) at (9,4);
\coordinate (p11) at (9.5,4.7);

% The cyan background
\fill[cyan!10] 
  (p2|-0,0) -- (p2) -- (p3) -- (p4) -- (p5) -- (p6) -- (p7) -- (p8) -- (p9) -- (p10) -- (p10|-0,0) -- cycle;
% the dark cyan stripe
\fill[cyan!30] (p6|-0,0) -- (p6) -- (p7) -- (p7|-0,0) -- cycle;
% the curve
\draw[thick,cyan] 
  (p1) to[out=70,in=180] (p2) to[out=0,in=150] 
  (p3) to[out=-50,in=230] (p4) to[out=30,in=220] 
  (p5) to[out=50,in=150] (p6) to[out=-30,in=180] 
  (p7) to[out=0,in=230] (p8) to[out=40,in=180] 
  (p9) to[out=-30,in=180] (p10) to[out=0,in=260] (p11);
% the broken line connecting points on the curve
\draw (p2) -- (p3) -- (p4) -- (p5) -- (p6) -- (p7) -- (p8) -- (p9) -- (p10);
% vertical lines and labels
\foreach \n/\texto in {2/{a=x_0},3/{x_1},4/{},5/{},6/{x_{j-1}},7/{x_j},8/{},9/{x_{n-1}},10/{b=x_n}}
{
  \draw (p\n|-0,0) -- (p\n);
  \node[below,text height=1.5ex,text depth=1ex,font=\small] at (p\n|-0,0) {$\texto$};
}
% The axes
\draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (10,0) coordinate (x axis);
\draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,6) coordinate (y axis);
% labels for the axes
\node[below] at (x axis) {$x$};
\node[left] at (y axis) {$y$};
% label for the function
\node[above,text=cyan] at (p11) {$y=f(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Gonzalo, I tried  your command but I can’t show in PDF Reader, I use compile  PDFTexify ,
In Execution Modes, I choose dvi >ps> pdf and compile to pdf , 
and I use WinEdt 6.0 as Text Editor. in my text editor show only   : "**!package pgf Error : No shape named p10 is known**"

Comment: @HirWanto did you try with the *exact* code I posted?

Comment: i tried more than five times ...  and i still can't show in PDF Reader

Comment: @HirWanto that's weird. The code runs without problems (I asked some friends of mine to also try the code and they had no problems). Could you please report the *exact* error message that you get?

Answer (score 9):

[image]

One more option for the fresh eyes - `Asymptote` approach. 
`trapez.asy`:

```
import graph;
size(400);
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}");

pair[] v={(7,12),(10,12.5),(15,10),(20,10),(25,13.5),(30,15),(35,13),(40,14),(45,15.5),(50,14),(53,15),};

int n=v.length;     // number of points

pen curvePen=blue+opacity(0.8)+1.2pt;     // definition of the pens to be used
pen axisPen=red+0.618pt;

pen fillA=rgb(0.67,0.91,0.98);
pen fillB=rgb(0.81,0.95,0.99);

real tickWidth=0.5;     
real xaxisTip=2;

guide g=graph(v,join=operator..);   // function curve, joined cubic segments
guide tg=graph(v,join=operator--);  // joined linear segments

fill(subpath(tg,1,n-2)--(v[n-2].x,0)--(v[1].x,0)--cycle,fillB); // basic area 
fill(subpath(tg,5,6)--(v[6].x,0)--(v[5].x,0)--cycle,fillA);     // area between x_{j-1} and x_j

draw(g,curvePen);   // draw a function curve

draw((v[1].x,-tickWidth)--v[1]); // draw a first vertical line
for(int i=2;i<n-1;++i){
  draw((v[i].x,-tickWidth)--v[i]--v[i-1]); // draw next vertical line and a top line 
}


int[] labelInd={1,2,5,6,8,9};   // indices of points with labels
string[] labelStr={             // labels
  "a=x_0","x_1","x_{j-1}","x_j","x_{n-1}","b=x_n"
};

string baselineTemplate="$";              // construction of the baseline template,
for(int i=0;i<labelStr.length;++i){       //   which contains all labels 
  baselineTemplate+=labelStr[i];          //   for the labels be placed on the same baseline
}
baselineTemplate+="$";

string s;
for(int i=0;i<labelInd.length;++i){         
  s=baseline("$"+labelStr[i]+"$"          // fixing baseline to the template
    ,template=baselineTemplate);
  label(s,(v[labelInd[i]].x,-tickWidth),S);  // placment of the label, "S" mean "to the South of"
}

label("$y=f(x)$",v[n-1],N,curvePen);      // one more label

xaxis(-2,v[n-1].x+xaxisTip,Arrow(HookHead,size=2),above=true,p=axisPen);
yaxis("$y$",-2,v[n-1].y,Arrow(HookHead,size=2),p=axisPen);

label(
  baseline("$x$",template=baselineTemplate),  // fixing the x-axis label to the same baseline,
  (v[n-1].x+xaxisTip,-tickWidth),S,axisPen    //   as the other labels along the axis
);
```

To get a standalone `trapez.pdf`,  run `asy -f pdf trapez.asy`.

Comment: Thank you for all ... i'm so happy for all your solution  , thank you... thank you

Answer (score 1):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\psset{algebraic,linejoin=2}

\def\f[#1]{sin(3*#1)/2+#1/3+1}
\def\Tick(#1)#2{%
    \rput[b](#1|0,-12pt){\small$#2$}
    \psline(#1|0,0)(#1|0,-2pt)
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-.25,-.5)(8.5,4.5)
    \fnpnodes[plotpoints=8]{.75}{7.5}{\f[x]}{P}
    \multido{\iL=0+1,\iR=1+1}{\Pnodecount}{\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan!15](P\iL|0,0)(P\iL)(P\iR)(P\iR|0,0)}
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan!35](P3|0,0)(P3)(P4)(P4|0,0)
    \psplot[plotpoints=100,linecolor=cyan!75!blue]{0.5}{7.75}{\f[x]}
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-.25,-.5)(8,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \Tick(P0){a=x_0}
    \Tick(P1){x_1}
    \Tick(P3){x_{j-1}}
    \Tick(P4){x_j}
    \Tick(P\the\numexpr\Pnodecount-1){x_{n-1}}
    \Tick(P\Pnodecount){b=x_n}
    \uput[90](*7.5 {\f[x]+.5}){\color{cyan!75!blue}$y=f(x)$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```