# Drawing the area under the curve of a function in LaTeX

Tags: graphs

Could you give me some guidance for producing a simple graph showing the integral of a function as the area under its curve?

Comment: Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47532/lower-and-upper-riemann-sums

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is a number of questions on the topic here; you may want to start having a look to: [Lower and upper Riemann sums](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47532/13304), [Trapezium rule for integration using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110598/13304), [Pgfplots: how to fill the area under a curve with oblique lines (hatching) as a pattern?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29359/13304)

Comment: Another: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/parabola-plot/