# Riemann sum with pgfplots -- can't seem to make graph look right

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to reproduce something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140213/27880) with the function `x^-1`, but no matter what options I try, I can't seem to make the graph look correct.

This is my current code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick={0,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17},ytick={0,...,1.5},
    xmax=18,ymax=1.2,ymin=0,xmin=0,
    enlargelimits=true,
    axis lines=middle,
    clip=false,
    domain=0:17,
    axis on top
    ]

\addplot [draw=red, fill=red!10, ybar interval, samples=9, domain=1:17]
    {x^-1}\closedcycle;
\addplot [draw=green, fill=green!10, const plot mark right, samples=9, domain=1:17]
    {x^-1}\closedcycle;

\addplot[smooth, thick,domain=1:17,samples=40]{x^-1};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the current output:

[image: LaTeX output]

How do I make the graph look correct, with the green outline for the green bars and without the green outline on the left of the first red bar (see output above)?

Comment: Probably not the solution you are looking for, but you could use `foreach \i in {1,3,...,17}` and draw a green line from `\i` to `1/\i`. Not very elegant because you superimpose lines... but better than nothing :D

Comment: For a PSTricks solution, see page 41--43 in the [pstricks-add](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-add) manual.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can fix this problem by using the `ybar interval` style for both plots, but reversing the direction for the lower sum by using `domain=17:1` instead of `domain=1:17`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick={0,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17},ytick={0,...,1.5},
    xmax=18,ymax=1.2,ymin=0,xmin=0,
    enlargelimits=true,
    axis lines=middle,
    clip=false,
    domain=0:17,
    axis on top
    ]

\addplot [draw=red, fill=red!10, ybar interval, samples=9, domain=1:17]
    {x^-1}\closedcycle;
\addplot [draw=green, fill=green!10, ybar interval, samples=9, domain=17:1]
    {x^-1}\closedcycle;

\addplot[smooth, thick,domain=1:17,samples=40]{x^-1};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a neat trick but it doesn't seem to work if `\addplot` specifies `gnuplot`. More generally, is there a way to get the box heights correspond to highest and lowest function values in each interval?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the lower rectangles in a `scope` environment and also `clip` to the correct height. Try replacing

```
\addplot [draw=green, fill=green!10, const plot mark right, samples=9, domain=1:17]
{x^-1}\closedcycle;
```

with

```
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (6.5cm,1.6cm);
\addplot [draw=green, fill=green!10, const plot mark right, samples=9, domain=1:17]
{x^-1}\closedcycle;
\end{scope}
```

I found the values 6.5cm and 1.6cm by trial and error. Don't know how to calculate these values automatically. Also, my version of `pgfplots` is 1.5, so the values may need adjusting.