# Rectangular Approximation Method (Riemann Sums) Diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Does anyone know how to make relatively simple diagrams like the images below? Is there a some sort of "template" I could use perhaps? I'd like to code my Calculus notes but I'm not sure how to make the diagrams. It's Left approximation, right approximation, and middle approximation, respectively. Alas...

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

Comment: Show the community that you've tried at least something. It goes a long way rather than just requesting people do-it-for-you.

Comment: search for riemann on this site

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197930/riemann-sum-with-pgfplots-cant-seem-to-make-graph-look-right, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140207/placing-coloured-rectangles-on-a-plot-using-points-from-the-plot-riemann-sums...

Comment: I'd highly recommend you spend the afternoon necessary to get a basic handle on `PGF/Tikz` and `PGFPlots` (the manuals for both are excellent!). They will draw figures like these in LaTeX, but will also make every figure you draw for the rest of your professional life look neater.

Answer (score 6):

Quick and dirty:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{declare function={y(\x)=4-\x^2;},
  plot fill/.style={fill=purple!75},
  plot/.style={draw=black!80, thick},
  bar/.style={fill=cyan, draw=white, thick},
  marking/.style={fill=cyan!50!black, draw=cyan!50!black},
  axis/.style={thick, draw=black!65, stealth-stealth}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, line cap=round, line join=round] 
\foreach \k [count=\z] in {0, 1/4, 1/2}{
\begin{scope}[shift=(0:\z*3)]
\path [plot fill] plot [domain=0:2] (\x,{y(\x)}) -| cycle;
\foreach \x in {0, 1/2, 1, 3/2}
   \path [bar]  (\x,0) |- (\x+1/2, {y(\x+\k)}) |- cycle;
\path [plot]  plot [domain=0:2] (\x,{y(\x)});
\path [axis] (0,4.5) |- (2.5,0);
\foreach \t [count=\x from 0] in {0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},2}
  \path [axis, -] (\x/2,0) -- ++(0,-3pt) node [below] {$\t$};
\foreach \y in {0,4}
  \path [axis, -] (0,\y) -- ++(-3pt, 0) node [left] {$\y$};
\foreach \x in {0, 1/2, 1, 3/2}
   \path [marking]  (\x+\k, {y(\x+\k)}) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest this solution, using my package `xpicture`. You can add colors, if you want, but for a more sophisticated design use the `tikzpicture` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{xpicture}
  \usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\newqpoly{\f}{4}{0}{-1}               % Define f(x)=4-x^2
\referencesystem(0,0)(2,0)(0,1)       % Change reference system to get a larger x-unit
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\xunitdivisions}{2}     % x-Tics at every half unit 
\begin{Picture}(-1,-1)(3,5)
  \cartesianaxes(-0.1,-0.1)(2.1,4.1)
  \printxticlabel{0.5}{1/2}
  \printxticlabel{1.5}{3/2}
  \PlotFunction[20]{\f}{0}{2}         % Plot f(x)
  \COPY{0}{\x}
  \whiledo{\lengthtest{\x pt}<2 pt}{% % Loop to plot Taylor sum
      \COPY{\x}{\xzero}
      \f{\xzero}{\yzero}{\Dyzero}     % yzero=f(xzero)
      \ADD{0.5}{\x}{\x}
      \Polyline(\xzero,0)(\xzero,\yzero)(\x,\yzero)(\x,0)
   }
\end{Picture}

\begin{Picture}(-1,-1)(3,5)
  \cartesianaxes(-0.1,-0.1)(2.1,4.1)
  \printxticlabel{0.5}{1/2}
  \printxticlabel{1.5}{3/2}
  \PlotFunction[20]{\f}{0}{2}
  \COPY{0}{\x}
  \whiledo{\lengthtest{\x pt}<2 pt}{%
      \COPY{\x}{\xzero}
      \ADD{0.5}{\x}{\x}
      \f{\x}{\y}{\Dy}                 % y=f(x)
      \Polyline(\xzero,0)(\xzero,\y)(\x,\y)(\x,0)
  }
  \end{Picture}

  \begin{Picture}(-1,-1)(3,5)
  \cartesianaxes(-0.1,-0.1)(2.1,4.1)
  \printxticlabel{0.5}{1/2}
  \printxticlabel{1.5}{3/2}
  \PlotFunction[20]{\f}{0}{2}
  \COPY{0}{\x}
  \whiledo{\lengthtest{\x pt}<2 pt}{%
      \COPY{\x}{\xzero}
      \ADD{0.5}{\x}{\x}
      \ADD{0.25}{\xzero}{\xm} 
      \f{\xm}{\ym}{\Dym}              % ym=f(xm)      
      \Polyline(\xzero,0)(\xzero,\ym)(\x,\ym)(\x,0)
  }
  \end{Picture}
  \end{document}
```