# How to plot the figure using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

If function is given, then I use goegebra to get the code of graph. But I do not know how to plot this figure in general using `tikz` code.

[image]

Comment: Did you at least try writing with `tikz`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Placing coloured rectangles on a plot, using points from the plot - Riemann Sums](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140207/placing-coloured-rectangles-on-a-plot-using-points-from-the-plot-riemann-sums) or [Timing and integration with TikZ PGFlots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30763) or [Riemann sum with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197930)